# PageFactory using Appium to test Windows desktop app

Tags: java, appium, desktop-application, winappdriver

I am used to test Android and IOS in Appium, but now doing some Windows PC application automation, and want to use the same design pattern as in mobile apps - Page Object.
For each element in my app I have `automationId` value, and I am trying to assign it using the `WindowsFindBy` annoatation, as follows:

```
@WindowsFindBy(id = "textBoxDirectory")
WebElement textBoxDirectory;
```

And I event tried using the accessibility value, but get the same result as you can see in driver logs.

```
@WindowsFindBy(accessibility = "textBoxDirectory")
WebElement textBoxDirectory;
```

The page constructor does this:

```
public PageObject(WindowsDriver driver) {
    this.driver = driver;
    PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
}
```

in WinAppDriver log, I see that the driver is trying to find the element by **name** and not by **ID** as expected:

```
{"using":"name","value":"textBoxDirectory"}
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Content-Length: 139
Content-Type: application/json

{"status":7,"value":{"error":"no such element","message":"An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters."}}
```

When I try to access the field the primitive way: `textBoxDirectory = driver.findElementByAccessibilityId("textBoxDirectory");` I get the element succesfully.

Thanks a lot for your help!